# Selenium IDE: How to Pass Variables

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have 3 different accounts in a website that I want to login and print a report every single day.

I've done a Selenium IDE recording that allows me to login and print the report, however, every day I have to change the variable 3 times (for the 3 different usernames and passwords).

How can I pass a variable to the "value" field of the "type" command?

Thank you.

Best,

Answer (score 16):

You can go with parameterization

For parameterization you need to create js file

For eg. Js file contains

```
var username = ["parameterization1@mailinator.com", "parameterization2@mailinator.com");
var password = ["parameterization1", "parameterization2"];
```

You can upload this JS file to Options > Options... > General tab > Selenium IDE extension.

Sample script for parameterization

[image]

Comment: `while` is not a native Selenium command. Is this using the [SelBlocks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/) extension?

Answer (score -6):

Try this way of using Selenium IDE - http://greenlanternautomationframework.blogspot.com/p/selenium-ide.html

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! that's a long page in the link, it would be better if you could summarize the part that is relevant to the question.

Comment: The link is dead by now - maybe having a summary would solve the problem :)