# About iteration in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am newbie/beginner to Selenium IDE, i am running a test on a web application. 
I wish to have a input of username into a textbox, let say 100 times how could i done this?
What i should type in the source or value column?

I want result somehow similar to

```
for (i=1;i<=100;i++)
{
   value = "user" + i ; 
}
```

(but i have no idea how to do it ...)

Then the test will going to loop 100 times and everytime will input different username like
User1 .... first time
User2 .... second time

Any helps would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use parametrization with looping, you can refer

[Selenium IDE: How to Pass Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588508/selenium-ide-how-to-pass-variables)

Answer (score 2):

This approach should also work as well, using the [SelBlocks extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/).

```
for   | i=1; i <= 100; i++      |
type  | id=fieldname            |user ${i}
endFor|                         |
```